# How to find out what WebDriverWait is successful?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a wait code for one of the items I need:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, 'XPATH') or driver.find_elements(
                By.XPATH, 'XPATH') or driver.find_elements(
                    By.XPATH, 'XPATH'))
```

Can I somehow find out which element I waited for?
I know that I can check for the existence of these elements like this:

```py
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'XPATH') > 0:
    True
elif driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'XPATH') > 0:
    True
```

But it is not as beautiful as I want. I am interested in the possibility of identification inside the until function.
If you have any other ideas I would love to hear them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `and` operator works in special way.
Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: (driver.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, 'XPATH1') and 1) or (driver.find_elements(
                By.XPATH, 'XPATH2') and 2) or (driver.find_elements(
                    By.XPATH, 'XPATH3') and 3))
```

This will return 1, 2 or 3 based on which XPATH was found. You can replace these numbers with any String/expression as well. Only condition is it should be an expression which can pass `if (expression)` in python.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't think the "and" would work like that. Is it a feature of working with a "lambda"?

Comment: @kshnkvn, This is not special behavior with `lambda`, this is how `and` normally works.